# Prevent firefox from asking to update managed password on input type password autocomplete="new-password"

Tags: html, firefox, input, autocomplete, passwords

In this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion in the last paragraph is stated:

> If you are defining a user management page where a user can specify a
> new password for another person, and therefore you want to prevent
> autofilling of password fields, you can use
> autocomplete="new-password".

- In my form, I display the credentials of another login (for an external API) and populate the values as stored on the server
- the credentials are not super sensitive, but to prevent leaking the password by reading it off the screen, I use input type=password
- when initially logging in to my webpage, I confirm and tell Firefox to store my credentials

Now, whenever I leave the page with the form, Firefox asks me, if I want to update the stored password `"Update login for xxx?" Update / Don't update`.

Is there some programmatic way to supress this behaviour?